# Trouble extracting specific information from log file

Tags: perl

I have the log file here I want to extract the following information

1. Want to extract hex value.
2. Want to extract the decimal value if the line has second bracket{0-9} first convert to hex then extract(9-->0x09)
3. Want to extract minus value(-25) first convert to hex then extract

   e.g.-25-->FFE7--> want to extract -->0xFF,0XE7
4. If the value is 0x2789 then split and join 0x(2789--> 0x27,0x89)

#### my_input_data

```
     my_info    0x2789  Uint16, unsigned short      
     param_id   0x14    Uint8,unsigned char     
     cell_id    0x05    Uint8,unsigned char     
     Indicator  0x0B    Uint8,unsigned char     
     filler1{3} { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }    Uint8,unsigned char     
     rscp_tap   -116    Sint8,signed char       
     filler2{3} { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00 }    Uint8,unsigned char     
     dsp    -101    Sint8,signed char       
     filler3{3} { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }    Uint8,unsigned char     
     system_fm_number   0x3601  Uint16, unsigned short      
     filler4{2} { 0x00, 0x00 }  Uint8,unsigned char 
     dsp_input      {7}
```

#### my expected output:

```
    0x27,0x89,0x14,0x05,0x0B,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFF,
    0x8C,0x01,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0x9B,0x36,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x07
```

#### my_code

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'true';

use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dumper;

# input variable pass as a input argument
my $variable_name = shift @ARGV;

# variable value pass as a input argument
my $variable_value = shift @ARGV;

#variable value need to be replaced with new value
my $Replacement_var = shift @ARGV;

# Name of the file the data is in
my $input_filename = 'input.txt';

# Name of the file you want to dump the output to
my $output_filename = 'output.txt';

# Open the file
open my $input_fh, "<", $input_filename or die $!;

# Open the output file
open my $output_fh, ">", $output_filename or die $!;

# Array to store the hex data
my @hex_array;
my @data_new;

# Loop over each of the lines of the file
while ( <$input_fh> ) {

    # Find all the matches and push them to the array

    if ( /$variable_name/ and /$variable_value/ ) {
        s/$variable_value/$Replacement_var/;
    }

    print $output_fh $_;

    #here  extracting only hex values from each line
    while ( $_ =~ m/(0x(\d+)(?:[0-9]|[A-f])+)/gi ) {
        push @hex_array, ( $1 );
    }
}

# Close the file
close $input_fh;

# Write the data to the file
@data_new = join( ", ", @hex_array );

print {$output_fh} @data_new;

# Close the file
close $output_fh;

# Exit
exit();
```

The above code works for extracting the hex value, but not for extracting 
the decimal {0-9} and minus -25 value and converting back to hex.

I think I need to modify the regex expression.

Comment: Use `split` to parse the line, take the second field unless it's a `{`, in which case you can take the next three if you need them (and strip the comma). Then parse the numbers.

Comment: @Borodin comments are not clear to me.please explain with some code.Thanks

Comment: I was waiting for the solutions is my question is clear ?

Comment: I'll take that comment to be merely clumsy, other than offensive as it may sound.   I understand you are expecting full solutions. However I didn't have time but still wanted to offer something that could be useful.  My comment should be of possibly good use if you've written all that posted code yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"I was waiting for the solutions"*

You urgently need to read and absorb [***How to ask***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

I don't understand why you have the three variables that you pull from `@ARGV` which you use to make substitutions in each line of input

Also, your code copies each modified line to the output file, but it doesn't appear in your "expected output"

You need to do more than finding some code on line that looks like it may work, and then hacking it a bit and putting it on Stack Overflow for others to finish for you. You have instantly lost many people's respect, and you may well struggle to get answers to further questions

This program does what you say you want

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ( $infile, $outfile ) = qw/ input.txt output.txt /;

open my $fh, '<', $infile  or die $!;

my @data;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    my ($f2) = / \S \s+ ( \{ [^{}]+ \} | \S+ ) /x;

    while ( $f2 =~ / 0x ( \p{hex}+ ) | ( [+-]?\d+ ) /xg ) {
        push @data, $1 // sprintf '%04X', $2 & 0xFFFF;
    }
}

{
    my $data = join ',', map "0x$_", map { unpack '(A2)*' } @data;

    open my $fh, '>', $outfile or die $!;
    print $fh $data, "\n";
    close $fh;
}
```

#### output

```
0x27,0x89,0x14,0x05,0x0B,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0x8C,0x01,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0x9B,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x36,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07
```

Comment: I have given three variable through @ARGV because in some case I want to change the input parameter(passing through command line) so I will be passing parameter type, old value and replace value so my code  first while loop is for reading through entire file by line by line. And second while loop is for extracting hex value.

Comment: @Abhishek: Please take your time and be more careful. It is very clear when someone has spent some effort on writing a question

Comment: yes..I am beginner in Perl scripting  and made many mistake while asking question in stack overflow..in future I will take care by doing this kind of mistake.

Comment: want to understand 1.my $data = join ',', map "0x$_", map { unpack '(A2)*' } @data; 2. p{hex}+

Comment: @Abhishek Work from right to left and use [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org) as a reference if you don't understand what one of the builtins does.

Comment: @Abhishek: It was my intention that you would want to understand my code. You were asking far too much from other people instead of trying something for yourself. There are many ways of solving your problem, and mine is only one.

Comment: @Abhishek: If this is a problem at work then you must say that you can't solve it. We offer ***help*** at Stack Overflow: we don't do other people's work.

Comment: @Abhishek: ***"I am beginner in Perl scripting and made many mistake while asking question in stack overflow..in future I will take care by doing this kind of mistake"*** You should start now. It doesn't look like you have spent more than ten minutes on your question. I have edited it but it is still a poor question, which is why you have no good answers.

Comment: @Borodin  in this regex my ($f2) = / \S \s+ ( \{ [^{}]+ \} | \S+ ) /x;
 I want to extract the value "0" from this line "meas_num PQRS_TN_CFG { 0}    meas_num" but its showing uninitialized value at $f2..

Comment: @Borodin I am debugging for  past two day but I could not figure out  why I am not able to extract "0" from this line "meas_num PQRS_TN_CFG { 0} meas_num"  please help me.